# EASY PYTHON SELENIUM: How do I hit CTRL + F?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/key_down-method-action-chains-in-selenium-python/) but I cannot get it to work. My goal is to hit CTRL + F. The page opens but nothing happens after that. Do you see any issues?

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/")

sleep(2)

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('f').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're required to include the `Key.up`, try:

```
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('f').perform()
```

Additional information can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/keyboard/).

Comment: Hey thank you for answering. Unfortunately it didn't work. Do you mind confirming whether it works on your end?